# Hilbert's irreducibility theorem for prime ideals

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, prime-ideals

A typical formulation of Hilbert's irreducibility theorem is like this <s>(see [1])</s>:

Let $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and $f\in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m]$ be an irreducible polynomial. There exists a Zariski <s>open</s> dense subset $V\subseteq k^n$ such that for every $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in V$ the polynomial $f(a_1,\ldots,a_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m)$ is irreducible in $k[y_1,\ldots,y_m]$.

Versions of the above can be found for the field $k$ being a number field. My question is: can we generalize this to the prime ideals. More precisely, **is the following true**:

> Let $k$ be a number field, let $k_0\subseteq k$ be a subfield, and let $\frak{p}$ be a prime ideal in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m]$ such that ${\frak p}\cap k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]=\{0\}$. There exists <s>a Zariski open subset $\style{text-decoration:line-through}{V\subseteq k^n}$</s> an $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in k^n\setminus k_0^n$ such that the ideal 
>   $$
>   \bar{\frak p}=\{\omega(a_1,\ldots,a_n,y_1,\ldots,y_m)\mid \omega\in{\frak p}\}
> $$
>   is a prime ideal of $k[y_1,\ldots,y_m]$.

A reference would be greatly appreciated.

<s>[1] M-D.Huang and Y.-Ch.Wong, Extended Hilbert irreducibility and its applications, J. Algorithms 37 (2000), no. 1, 121–145.</s>

Comment: You need to add the hypothesis that $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to k[x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_m]/\mathfrak{p}$ is an injective homomorphism.  Assuming this, your formulation reduces to the usual formulation by applying the Noether Normalization Theorem to the integral closure, $A$, of $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with respect to that morphism.  There exists an element $z$ in $A$ such that the induced morphism $k[x_1,\dots,x_n,z]\to A$ becomes surjective with principal kernel $\langle f \rangle$ after inverting a nonzero element $g\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.  Now apply the usual theorem to $f\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n,z]$.

Comment: @Adam Przeździecki Your `typical formulation' of Hilbert's irreducibility theorem is false. Take e.g. $m=n=1$ and $f=y_1^2-x_1$. Thus $f(y_1,a_1)$ is reducible for infinitely many rational $a_1$'s, so a Zariski open subset of the rationals avoiding these numbers is the empty set.

Comment: @Peter Mueller: The result stated in OP's question is true, just take $V$ to be empty. Presumably OP meant Zariski dense instead of Zariski open.

Comment: @js21 The stated result is true, but it is *not* Hilbert's irreducibility theorem.

Comment: @PeterMueller Thanks, the "formulation" was copied from the paper cited. This also explains why I could not find this formulation in the Lang's book from which it was supposedly taken.